# Time Machine for non-hard-drives

Tags: macos, mac, backup, time-machine

Is there a good method or application for backing up USB keys with Time Machine? Often I take my work from one computer to another on a USB key and thus that is where the most recent version of it lives. However, USB keys are not covered by time machine. Is there a way to change this? Currently, I periodically copy the contents of my USB key to a folder on my desktop and then get Time Machine's backups that way. However, I often forgot and don't do it as often as I should. What would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here: [How to Automatically Back Up Your USB Flash Drive in OS X](http://www.lockergnome.com/osx/2007/12/19/how-to-automatically-backup-your-usb-flash-drive-in-os-x/)

Follow the link after the post, it explains how to create a script. The other option is to follow what is mentioned in the comments section and format the USB to be HFS+. This however makes the USB useless if you wanted to use it on a Windows machine.